# creating the sphinx conf file

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

i have a query as below

```
select SystemId, Id, FirstName, LastName,AptUnitNo, Zip, StreetName,streetnumber (case when LastName like 'robe%' then -8 else 0 end ) as Ordervalue 
from registeredusers 
Where LastName like 'robe%') 
order by Ordervalue, LastName,FirstName , StreetName, StreetNumber ASC 
limit 0,50
```

how to create a sphinx conf file for the above query.

dell

Comment: Are you trying to install sphinx ?

Comment: yes. i have already installed it. but facing difficulty with how to implement it in sphinx as i have about 4 dynamic queries based on lastname,firstname,streetname,zip. and need the best match based on the criteria.

Comment: hey Moyed ansari .. let me know if u have implemented sphinx before ..

Comment: yes, i know how to install and configure sphinx

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your query to the sql_query option in the config file.

You can find step by step guide on how to create config file, perform initial indexing and run your first Sphinx query here: http://astellar.com/2011/12/replacing-mysql-full-text-search-with-sphinx/